# What is the meaning of the simile “quick as silk”?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

It seems that the Internet is unhelpful at all. The original quote, where this simile appears, is:

> “Once upon a time,” began Frank switching, quick as silk, to a
>   sonorous story-telling voice...

The full story may be checked on Google Books, from [page 419](https://books.google.com/books?id=EcfqAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA419&lpg=PA419) of *Mammoth Deception* (2013) by Aleta Whitaker.

Comment: As none of the answers directly answer the title, it clearly means _quick_. Quite why the author thought silk quick, whether that was quick in the sense of "fast" or of "alive", and whether the author is alone in this or a mistake, is a matter of opinion addressed below. But for the direct answer: it means _quick_.

Answer (score 17):

I think the cited usage is something of a [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) / mixed metaphor. It should be one of either...

> *switching, [as]  [**quick as a flash**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quick%20as%20a%20flash%22) [to something else]*
>    OR
>    *switching, [as]  [**smooth as silk**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22smooth%20as%20silk%22) [to something else]*

Note that both the above expressions occur many times in Google Books (which I've linked to). But there are virtually no instances of ***quick as silk*** or ***smooth as a flash***

Obviously there's often a difference between doing something ***quickly*** and doing it ***smoothly***, but in the exact context they're much the same. It's *possible* the writer was being deliberately quirky by mixing up the two expressions (perhaps in order to *force* the reader to explicitly recognise both nuances). But I kinda doubt it - most likely it's just a "mistake".

Answer (score 8):

It is almost certainly a mistake, as the expression "quick as silk" not only makes no sense (silk has no speed) but it cannot be found anywhere else.

This is not strictly a "malapropism", as it is unlikely one would hear "flash" and think it was "silk". A malapropism is when someone gets an idiom wrong by substituting a similar sounding word, eg "*he danced the flamingo*" (instead of "flamenco").

Neither it is a "mixed metaphor", as this is a statement that contains two incompatible comparisons, for example "*we need to iron out the bugs*" (who irons bugs? It should be *iron out the creases* or *crush the bugs*).

I think what you have on your hands is a *Malaphor* - an incorrect mixture of two idioms, or clichés, also called an *idiom blend*.

Comment: *Quick as a wink* and *quick as a whip* are somewhat similar-sounding clichés. I thought this might have been a literary usage of *quick* in the archaic sense of liveliness, referring to the shimmering of silk, but after researching the author some, that may be giving her too much credit.

Comment: Just on the off-chance, I checked out Google Books for [*as **quick** as ninepence.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+quick+as+ninepence%22) As expected, there were a handful of results, but they're dwarfed by *thousands* of hits for the "correct" version [*as **right** as ninepence*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+right+as+ninepence%22). Would I call that a "blend"? No - I'd say it's *never* a "deliberate" usage. It's just a *mistake*.

Comment: @choster: It's usually [*as **smart** as a whip*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+*+as+a+whip&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cas%20%2A%20as%20a%20whip%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bas%20smart%20as%20a%20whip%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20sharp%20as%20a%20whip%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20thin%20as%20a%20whip%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20well%20as%20a%20whip%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bas%20quick%20as%20a%20whip%3B%2Cc0) (but ***quick*** isn't totally unknown).

Comment: ...I even found one instance of [*as **ripe** as ninepence.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+ripe+as+ninepence%22) But glancing at the surrounding text, I'd be quite prepared to believe *that* one was a deliberately facetious "mangling".

Comment: "Quick as silk" also found at.... http://www.wintertangerine.com/wang-wu-daozi-dreaming ...... Not that that makes it a recognized idiom,...just sayin'.

Comment: "Slick as silk" would even be OK -- could be more or less of a typo?

Comment: It could be a typo or mistake, but it's perfectly possible that it's a deliberate use of a mixed metaphor, suggesting a transition that was BOTH quick as a wink AND smooth as silk, for example. Not every use of an alternate wording must be a mistake.

Comment: It could be deliberate - see phrases like "_That boy's as sharp as a bowling ball_" </foghorn_legcorn>, which is to say - not sharp.  Also one of my favorites: "_Got a mind like a steel sieve_", which also means the opposite of the usual phrase.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that to me, a native speaker, "quick as silk" *does* make sense. Not if I really think about it, but hearing the phrase, I get what it means. Silk is smooth, so you can run your hand across it quickly. It works.

Answer (score 5):

If we assume the author didn't make a mistake here, then it feels to me like a reference to silk's "slipperiness" - imagine two pieces of silk cloth sliding over each other: fast and friction-less.

Answer (score 4):

It may not be a common metaphor, but it makes perfect sense if you know what [shot silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_silk) is - basically, it is silk fabric made with different colored warp and weft threads, so that every slight movement of the cloth changes the patterns of color you see.

Frank made a rapid shift from making a reference to a dirty joke about a princess, to retelling the story in elaborately "politically correct" language (she "sat contemplating ecological issues" etc).